# Formato de salida comando Powershell en Python

Tags: python, powershell

Tengo una duda acerca del formato de salida del siguiente comando:

```
model = "(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName .).Model"

print(subprocess.call("powershell "+model))
```

Este comando me devuelve el modelo del equipo de forma correcta si lo ejecuto en powershell:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si lo ejecuto a través de Python me devuelve este formato:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me hace un salto de línea y me añade ese "0", y quisiera que no saliera ni tampoco el salto de línea.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo **único** que quieres es que no te salga el código de retorno, simplemente quita el print:

```
subprocess.call("powershell "+model)
```

Si más adelante lo que quieres es trabajar con ese output, por ejemplo como un string, [aquí tienes otra respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861508/how-to-prevent-subprocess-call-from-printing-return-code)